# Approximate simultaneous block-diagonalization of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you are given two symmetric real matrices $A$ and $B$, each $k \times k$. Fix an index $r$, $1 \leq r \leq k-1$. Is there an invertible linear transformation that simultaneously transforms each of these matrices into the following form: a block on the diagonal of size $r \times r$, followed by a block on the diagonal of size $(k-r-1) \times (k-r-1)$, followed by the last row and last column being filled with (possibly nonzero) entries?